# Поиск прямых которые не пересекаются в прямоугольной матрице

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

Задана прямоугольная матрица размером nxm. Матрица заполнена числами от 0 до 9, которые обозначают цвет. Найти прямую или прямые с самой большой длиной и их цвет. Вывести в консоль координаты начала и конца прямой, ее длину и цвет. Надо искать прямые вертикально, горизонтально и по диагонали(45 градусов, в направлении основной диагонали матрицы). Прямые не могут пересекаться. Если есть несколько прямых одинаковой длинны вывести все.

Кругом прямой одного цвета должны быть квадраты других цветов т.е если под прямой из единиц есть единица эта прямая нам не подходит как на фото

[image: На пример для для такой матрицы]

должно вывести `A[1,3]-A[2,4] длина 2, цвет 7`

Написала такой код и не могу понять как делать поиск

```
C#
using System;
namespace lb_h
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("enter n: ");
            var n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("enter m: ");
            var m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var matrix = new int[n, m];
            int size;
            var coordsBeg = "";
            var coordsEnd = "";
            var lineLen = "";

            var rd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = rd.Next(10);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----your matrix-----");

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]} ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // search from left to right
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var flag = i == n;
                for (var j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
                {
                    size = 0;
                    var temp = matrix[i, j];

                    if (temp != matrix[i, j + 1] || (flag ? false : (temp != matrix[i + 1, j + 1])))
                    {
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашем примере самая длинная прямая из единичек.

Comment: @tym32167 `Прямые не могут пересекаться.`

Comment: `Прямые не могут пересекаться` вот это требует пояснений

Comment: @aepot прямые, если они не параллельные, то они пересакающиеся. У пряфмых нет начала и конца. Отрезки, у которых есть начало и конец, могут пересекаться. Поскольку у автора путаница с терминами, я и хотел бы уточнить, что значит `Прямые не могут пересекаться`. К тому же не понятно, это относится к одному цвету или к любому.

Comment: может ли отрезок одного цвета считаться пересекающимся с отрезком другого цвета?

Comment: @aepot да, может

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачка казалась на первый взгляд сложной, но интересной. Ключом к решению было разбить ее на множество мелких задач и реализовать для каждой подзадачи отдельный метод.

#### Структуры данных

**Точка**

Умеет только хранить координаты и выводить себя в консоль

```cs
struct Point
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"[{X},{Y}]";
}
```

**Линия**

Хранит свое начало, конец, цвет и может вычислять свою длину, возвращать все свои точки, а так же проверять, пересекается ли она с другой линией.

Пересечение означает наличие общей точки.

```cs
struct Line
{
    public Point Start { get; }
    public Point End { get; }
    public int Color { get; }
    public int Length { get; }
    public Point[] Points { get; }

    public Line(Point start, Point end, int color)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        Color = color;
        Length = Math.Max(Math.Abs(end.X - start.X), Math.Abs(end.Y - start.Y)) + 1;
        Point[] points = new Point[Length];
        if (Length > 0)
        {
            points[0] = Start;
            if (Length > 1)
            {
                points[Length - 1] = End;
                if (Length > 2)
                {
                    int xDirection = Math.Sign(End.X - Start.X);
                    int yDirection = Math.Sign(End.Y - Start.Y);
                    for (int i = 1; i < Length - 1; i++)
                        points[i] = new Point(Start.X + xDirection * i, Start.Y + yDirection * i);
                }
            }
        }
        Points = points;
    }

    public bool IsCrossing(Line other)
        => Points.Any(point => other.Points.Contains(point));

    public override string ToString()
        => $"{Start}-{End} длина {Length}, цвет {Color}";
}
```

#### Приложение

- `RandomizeMatrix` заполняет матрицу случайными числами
- `PrintMatrix` печатает матрицу в консоль, выделяя зеленым цветом переданные в массиве линии
- `FilterCrossLines` убирает из массива линий пересекающиеся линии
- `GetAllLines` находит все возможные линии в матрице
- `TryCreateLineFromMatrix` пытается создать линию в матрице из указанной точки в указанном направлении

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //int[,] matrix = new int[,]
        //{
        //    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        //    { 1, 1, 5, 7, 8 },
        //    { 1, 3, 1, 6, 7 },
        //    { 1, 0, 9, 1, 8 },
        //};

        Console.Write("Enter n: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter m: ");
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] matrix = new int[n, m];
        RandomizeMatrix(matrix);

        Line[] lines = GetAllLines(matrix);
        Line[] filteredLines = FilterCrossLines(lines)
            .GroupBy(line => line.Length)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Last().ToArray();
        PrintMatrix(matrix, filteredLines, lines);
        foreach (Line line in filteredLines)
            Console.WriteLine(line);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void RandomizeMatrix(int[,] matrix)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(10);
    }

    static void PrintMatrix(int[,] matrix, Line[] lines, Line[] allLines)
    {
        Point[] allPoints = lines.SelectMany(l => l.Points).ToArray();
        Point[] totalPoints = allLines.SelectMany(l => l.Points).Distinct().ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (allPoints.Contains(new Point(j, i)))
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                else
                if (totalPoints.Contains(new Point(j, i)))
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                else
                    Console.ResetColor();
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    static Line[] FilterCrossLines(Line[] lines)
    {
        List<Line> result = new List<Line>(lines);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
                if (i != j && lines[i].IsCrossing(lines[j]))
                    result.Remove(lines[i]);
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    static Line[] GetAllLines(int[,] matrix)
    {
        List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                Point point = new Point(j, i);
                if (TryCreateLineFromMatrix(matrix, point, 1, 0, out Line line))
                {
                    lines.Add(line);
                    j += line.Length - 1;
                }
            }

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            {
                Point point = new Point(j, i);
                if (TryCreateLineFromMatrix(matrix, point, 0, 1, out Line line))
                {
                    lines.Add(line);
                    i += line.Length - 1;
                }
            }

        for (int i = -matrix.GetLength(1) + 1; i < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
                if (i + j >= 0 && i + j < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1)
                {
                    Point point = new Point(j, i + j);
                    if (TryCreateLineFromMatrix(matrix, point, 1, 1, out Line line))
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                        j += line.Length - 1;
                    }
                }

        return lines.ToArray();
    }

    static bool TryCreateLineFromMatrix(int[,] matrix, Point start, int xDirection, int yDirection, out Line line)
    {
        int color = matrix[start.Y, start.X];
        int x = start.X;
        int y = start.Y;
        int maxRight = matrix.GetLength(1) - start.X;
        int maxDown = matrix.GetLength(0) - start.Y;
        int maxLength = xDirection + yDirection == 2 ? Math.Min(maxRight, maxDown)
            : yDirection > 0 ? maxDown
            : xDirection > 0 ? maxRight
            : 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            if (matrix[y + yDirection, x + xDirection] != color)
                break;
            x += xDirection;
            y += yDirection;
        }

        bool created = x != start.X || y != start.Y;
        line = created ? new Line(start, new Point(x, y), color) : default(Line);
        return created;
    }
}
```

#### Вывод в консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным отмечены все найденные линии, зеленым - соответствующие условию задачи.

Comment: Как бы вы оценили время работы (O(n)) алгоритма в итоге?

Comment: @tym32167 сложность? Квадратичная вроде-как. Но я на гениальность и не претендую. В условии не указаны ограничения по размеру матрицы, следовательно я не тестил скорость на потенциально максимальных значениях.

Comment: да я не в укор, я просто начал решать это с утра, но не успел дорешать перед работой. Теперь думаю, дорешивать или нет )

Comment: походу тут будет О(длина матрицы х ширина матрицы х количество линий х количество точек в линии).

Comment: @tym32167 ну я пытался поймать все линии в один проход, чтобы не итерироваться трижды, была мысль просто просканировать горизонтали, вертикали и диагонали и выдернуть все последовательности длиной 2 и больше, но подумал, что как сейчас, будет прикольнее.

Comment: А я начал с вертикалей-горизонталей-диагоналей. Пожалуй попробую допилить, там по идее будет что то около линейной скорости, но съест больше памяти

Comment: @tym32167 как по мне, так `длина матрицы х ширина матрицы + количество линий x количество точек в линии`

Comment: У вас же в `GetAllLines(int)` 4 цикла вложенных + в других паре методах по 3 цикла.

Comment: @tym32167 я слаб в оценке сложностей, поэтому люблю Benchmark.NET

Comment: Ну он не покажет алгоритмическую сложность, но да, инструмент хороший :)

Comment: @tym32167 подоптимизировал `GetPoints()` чтоб не так страшно было :)

Comment: хех, а я и не заметил, что там новый список создавался. Круть :)

Comment: вопрос по поводу вашего скрина, вот [этого](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtwsM.png) - там вроде две восьмерки подряд по горизонтали, это должно быть линей?

Comment: @tym32167 вроде все поправил. Кстати, перешел на раздельное сканирование.

Comment: добавил свой вариант

Answer (score 3):

Я решил воспользоваться фактом, что мы рассматриваем только 3 варианта линий: горизонтальные, вертикальные и по главной диагонали. Линии одного типа пересекаться не могут. Таким образом, мы можем сначала получить все линии по отдельности, а после проверить, которые из них пересекаются.

```
var matrix = new int[,] {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {1, 1, 5, 7, 8},
    {1, 3, 1, 6, 7},
    {1, 0, 9, 1, 8},
};  

int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);

var checkH = new(int x, int y)[rows, cols];
var checkV = new(int x, int y)[rows, cols];
var checkD = new(int x, int y)[rows, cols];

var empty = (-1, -1);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        checkH[i, j] = empty;
        checkV[i, j] = empty;
        checkD[i, j] = empty;
    }
```

В этой функции мы по начальной точке и направлению найдем конец линии с тем же цветом. По сути в каждой ячейке линии мы запишем координаты её начала.

```
void CheckDirection((int x, int y) start, (int dx, int dy) step, (int, int)[,] check)
{
    var (xend, yend) = start;
    int count = 0;
    while (xend < matrix.GetLength(0) && yend < matrix.GetLength(1)
     && matrix[xend, yend] == matrix[start.x, start.y])
    {
        check[xend, yend] = start;
        (xend, yend) = (xend + step.dx, yend + step.dy);
        count++;
    }
    
    if (count == 1) check[start.x, start.y] = empty;
}
```

Находим все вертикальные, горизонтальные и диагональные линии

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        if (checkH[i, j] == empty)
            CheckDirection((i, j), (0, 1), checkH);

        if (checkV[i, j] == empty)
            CheckDirection((i, j), (1, 0), checkV);

        if (checkD[i, j] == empty)
            CheckDirection((i, j), (1, 1), checkD);
    }
}
```

Нахоим все пересечения линий и пишем начало пересекаюзихся линий в набор для игнорирования

```
var haveIntersections = new HashSet<(int, int)>();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        if (checkH[i, j] != empty) cnt++;
        if (checkV[i, j] != empty) cnt++;
        if (checkD[i, j] != empty) cnt++;

        if (cnt > 1)
        {
            haveIntersections.Add(checkH[i, j]);
            haveIntersections.Add(checkV[i, j]);
            haveIntersections.Add(checkD[i, j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну тут все просто, надо пройтись по всем линиями, что не пересекались, и найти самые длинные

```
int maxLen = 0;
var lines = new HashSet<((int x1, int y1) start, (int x2, int y2) end, int len, int color)>();

void udateMaxLen((int i, int j) start, (int i, int j) end)
{
    if (start == empty) return;
    if (haveIntersections.Contains(start)) return;
    if (haveIntersections.Contains(end)) return;

    var len = Math.Max(end.i - start.i, end.j - start.j);
    if (len > maxLen)
    {
        maxLen = len;
        lines.Clear();
        lines.Add((start, end, len, matrix[start.i, start.j]));
    }

    if (len == maxLen)
        lines.Add((start, end, len, matrix[start.i, start.j]));
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        udateMaxLen(checkH[i, j], (i, j));
        udateMaxLen(checkV[i, j], (i, j));
        udateMaxLen(checkD[i, j], (i, j));
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
foreach (var line in lines) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.start}-{line.end}, len={line.len+1}, color={line.color}");
```

Результат

```
(1, 3)-(2, 4), len=2, color=7
```

Код я причесывать не стал, оставлю как есть.
Скорость работы алгоритма линейная - асимптотически быстрее алгоритма не придумать.
Память кушает тоже линейно.

Comment: Матрица координат :) ловко. Плюсанул.

Comment: Протестил. Не всегда, но иногда выдает лишнего, ну и координаты в выводе местами поменяны https://i.stack.imgur.com/yueXk.png

Comment: Еще кейз https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyaYJ.png

Comment: @aepot обновил, можете ещё раз глянуть на корректность?

Comment: теперь вроде все ок стало.

Comment: @aepot круть! спасибо :)